# Projecting a cube onto a plane using matrix transformations and numpy

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I wasn't sure if this topic was a better fit here or on math overflow. Since I'm using numpy, I thought I'd post it here.

I'm trying to rotate a cube in 3 dimensional space and then project it onto a 2 dimensional plane.

I begin with the Identiy Matrix:

```
import numpy as np

I = [[1,0,0],
     [0,1,0],
     [0,0,1]]
```

Then, I apply a rotational transformation to the Y Axis:

```
from math import sin, cos

theta = radians(30)
c, s = cos(theta), sin(theta)
RY = np.array([[c, 0, s],[0, 1, 0], [-s, 0, c]])
# at this point I'd be dotting the Identiy matrix, but I'll include for completeness
I_RY = np.dot(I, RY)
```

At this point I have a new basis space that has been rotated 30 degrees about the Y axis.

Now, I want to project this onto a 2-dimensional space. I figured, this new space is basically the identity basis with the Z axis set to zero:

```
FLAT = [[1,0,0],
        [0,1,0],
        [0,0,0]]
```

So now, I figure I can compose with this to complete a full transformation from cube to square:

```
NEW_SPACE = np.dot(I_RY, FLAT)
```

All that's left is to transform the points of the original cube. Assuming that the original cube had its northeast points set to [1,1,1] and [1,1,-1], I can get the new points like so:

```
NE_1 = np.array([1,1,1])
NE_2 = np.array([1,1,-1])
np.dot(NEW_SPACE, NE_1)
np.dot(NEW_SPACE, NE_2)
```

However, this gives me the following:

```
array([ 0.8660254,  1.       , -0.5      ])
```

This sort of checks out, because both points have been flattened to the same thing. However, what is the `-0.5` in the Z axis? What does it represent?

The existence of a value on the Z axis post transformation makes me think that my method is incorrect. Please tell me if I'm going about this the wrong way.

Comment: Just as an FYI, I am not a student, so please do not suggest "asking my instructor". I am a fulltime programmer, learning this on the side.

Comment: Looks like order of multiplication to me. You seem to multiply your vectors with the projection first and then with the rotation. It should probably be the other way round.

Comment: How do? I'm doing `I -> RY -> FLAT`

Comment: Well, yes, and then you are multiplying `NE_1/2` with that _from the right_ so it is like multiplying with `FLAT` first. (Recall that matrix multiplication is _associative_, meaning that bracketing (the temporal order if you wish) doesn't matter, but not _commutative_, meaning that the left-right order does matter.)

Comment: @PaulPanzer, you were right, please submit your response as an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3):

As @PaulPanzer pointed out, I was dotting the new vector from the wrong direction. The solution is

```
np.dot(NE_1, NEW_SPACE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. The 3d pipeline to transform your cube vertices is

`projection @ camera @ world @ model @ vertices`

Your FLAT matrix is a [camera matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_matrix?oldformat=true) with `focal_length=1` and `cx = cy = 0` (screen offsets).

[punyty](https://github.com/jsheedy/punyty) is a small demonstration engine for rendering 3d models using numpy if you want a reference.